# ssh'ing from Windows machine to Ux with public key to avoid typing passwd, with putty

Tags: ssh

I have a local workstation Running Windows called myDesktop where I'm logged on with user name 'windowsLogin', and a Linux target server called myLinux, where I must ssh-log with user 'linuxLogin'.

From MobaXterm running on the Windows machine, I can  generate a key and copy it to myLinux:

```
local$ /bin/ssh-keygen
local$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub |ssh myLinux 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
local$ ssh myLinux      <========= OK fine it worked !
```

This `id_rsa.pub` contains now a line ending up with "windowsLogin@MYDESKTOP".

How do I achieve the same with putty as that stills asks me for a password, i.e. password of user specified in putty saved session under Connection -> Data in field 'Auto-login username' (which is different from my OS desktop 'windowsLogin')...

I already tried:

- replacing the auto-login user name with my linuxLogin
- to click 'Use system username (Seb FamilyName)' by leaving the field 'Auto-login username' empty...
- copying the public key generated by puttygen on myLInux in .ssh/authrorized_keys
  (string ending up with "rsa-key-20180111")

And none of those work...

*Is it  possible to get putty working with an ssh key to avoid typing a password?*

Comment: Putty needs its key in a different format - http://meinit.nl/using-your-openssh-private-key-in-putty

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, yes it's perfectly possible. You can either import/convert the existing OpenSSH private key into PuTTY's PPK format using `puttygen`, or generate a new keypair using `puttygen` and copy the OpenSSH-compatible public key to the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

Comment: "Is it really possible to get putty working with ssh key to avoid typing a password all the while? "  Yes, it is.  It's been working fine for something over 15 years now with many versions of windows on one side and linux/hpux/solaris/*bsd on the other.  This reads more as a rant than a focused question appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use key pair authentication with PuTTY.  However, PuTTY expects a different format for private key files.  Use the included `PuTTYgen` program to convert the private key you generated with `ssh-keygen` to one PuTTY can use (or alternatively generate a new keypair for your Windows box to use with PuTTY).